# Remapping of vim direction keys is not honored by viewport navigation

Tags: vim, viewport, keymapping, colemak

I am using colemak and thus I have remapped my direction keys like so

```
noremap n h
noremap e j
noremap i k
noremap o l

noremap h n
noremap j e
noremap k i
noremap l o
```

The problem is that these keybindings are not honored by the viewport navigation. Eg. when I press `^w+n` I want to shift focus to the viewport to the left but instead a new empty viewport is opened.

How can I help rebinding all the viewport navigation keys individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to map the `<C-W>` window navigation commands explicitly, by doing something like:

```
noremap <C-W>n <C-W>h
noremap <C-W>e <C-W>j
noremap <C-W>i <C-W>k
noremap <C-W>o <C-W>l

noremap <C-W>h <C-W>n
noremap <C-W>j <C-W>e
noremap <C-W>k <C-W>i
noremap <C-W>l <C-W>o
```

Comment: This what I'd like to avoid. I don't understand why my remaps doesn't work. I'd also have to remap the uppercase version of the above commands.

Comment: When you type `<C-w>`, you ask Vim to wait for another keypress. At that moment I don't think you can consider yourself in _NORMAL_ mode anymore, hence your _NORMAL_ mode mappings not working.

Comment: romainl: My bindings are definitely NOT normal mode mappings. They are the standard binding mode applying to both normal, visual and operator-pending mode. Normal mode bindings would have been `nnoremap`.

Answer (score 2):

This subject has been somewhat beaten to death over at the colemak forums:

- http://colemak.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=50 (5 pages, with active contributions by the designer of colemak, who (used to be) an avid vim user too).

There are a number of listed links to

- keymaps
- plugin scripts

I feel Shai's own script is going way too far - doing way more than just integrate Colemak into vim (remapping C-w to Close Tab e.g., showing some bias towards tab-oriented editors, people have complained about in-/exclusive motions (diw, daB etc) not working any more etc).

I guess the best advice, as has been given before is to [stick with the defaults](http://www.ryanheise.com/colemak/) and do:

> #### Keyboard bindings for Vim
>
> Vim is an extremely efficient text editor that I use for writing emails and
>   editing any sort of text file. Vim's commands are all controlled from the
>   keyboard: 'd' for delete, 'w' to move the cursor forward one word, 'dw' to
>   delete the text moved over by 'w', '2dw' to delete two words, etc.
>   Left/Down/Up/Right navigation is located on the QWERTY keys H/J/K/L so that
>   the typist's hands never need to reach for arrow keys or the mouse.
>
> Unfortunately, these navigation keys are not so intuitive under Colemak and
>   so I needed to find some more appropriate mappings. After experimenting with
>   many alternatives, here is what I finally decided on and am very happy with:
>
> ```
> noremap n j|noremap <C-w>n <C-w>j|noremap <C-w><C-n> <C-w>j
> noremap e k|noremap <C-w>e <C-w>k|noremap <C-w><C-e> <C-w>k
> noremap s h
> noremap t l
>
> noremap f e
> noremap k n
> noremap K N 
> noremap U <C-r>
> ```